# Is there any challenge in using SQL Setup file from one SQL Azure VM on another Windows VM?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a customer who has created only Windows VM from Azure Gallery and wants me to install SQL in it. Is it ok to use SQL Setup file from another Azure VM on this VM?
If yes, then it makes no sense as people can now ask for Windows VM instead of SQL VM which are more expensive and get around it by using SQL setup file from another SQL Azure VM.

Comment: You still have to pay the SQL Server license. You don't pay for the setup file - you can download it directly from Microsoft.

Comment: In any case, this question is out-of-scope for StackOverflow. The answer is clearly explained in Microsoft's sites and Azure. Either you buy a VM with a licensed SQL Server, or you pay your own license.

Comment: I am actually aware of that. i need to know if i will face any technical error if i copy and execute the setup file from a different server. Like i mentioned in my previous comment, invoice didnt contain sql fees if sql was manually installed on windows vm.

Comment: Again, you can *download* that file from Microsoft directly and pick the edition you want to install during setup. If you don't install the Developer edition you'll have to insert a product key. You can download the ISO if you want. You *still* have to buy and insert a license key.

Comment: And this question is *still* out of scope for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Where you get the install bits isn't as important as the licensing model. There are two licensing models for a virtual machine (VM) hosting SQL Server - pay-as-you-go, and bring your own license (BYOL). And now, using either PowerShell or Azure CLI, you can modify which licensing model your SQL Server VM uses.

Full documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-ahb).

Comment: sql licensing model change is meant for vms which are created using sql server image from gallery. It doesnt come into picture if the vm is built using windows image from gallery

Comment: @user2756234 no. It applies *always*. You install SQL Server, you pay and bring your own license. If you use a SQL Server VM the license is included in the cost.

Comment: actually, this was tested by microsoft team themselves. they have noticed that the invoice for the vm didnt show sql charges if it was manually installed. you may want to test it

Comment: right if you manually install SQL you need to license it (BYOL).  Just because the system allows you to do something doesn't mean it's properly licensed.  I would suggest you speak to a licensing expert to ensure you are in compliance if you go this route.